# Does the rubber washer on an outdoor conduit whip go inside the box or outside?

Tags: electrical, well-pump

I'm replacing the power whip to a well pump. It's unclear which side the rubber washer goes on to create a water tight seal with the disconnect box.

Is it:

```
Whip -> Washer -> Hole in Box -> Nut (rubber washer outside box)
```

Or:

```
Whip -> Hole in Box -> Washer -> Nut (rubber washer inside box)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first:

Whip -> Washer -> Hole in Box -> Nut (rubber washer outside box)

not

<del>Whip -> Hole in Box -> Washer -> Nut (rubber washer inside box)</del>

You want the plastic washer on the outside for a watertight seal, and the nut on the box for mechanical strength and with a metal box, to bond the fitting to the box electrically.

Comment: The washer that came with is a fat rubber one that's rounded. Still on the outside?

Comment: Yes, same idea - when you tighten the locknut it will squeeze the soft washer between the body of the fitting and the box, sealing it up well.  If the rubber washer was under the locknut it would get chewed up as you tightened it.